# Which PHP tags are always available?

Tags: php

Of the 4 types of PHP tags:

- **Standard** tag : `<?php ...?>`
- **Short** tag : `<? .... ?>`
- **Script** tag: `<script language=“php”>
  ... </script>`
- **ASP** tag : `<% ... %>`

Which is/are ***always*** available ?

Comment: sounds like someone's studying for their Zend Certification :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard `<?php` and the `<script>` tags are always available.

The two others depend on configuration settings.

From the [reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php):

> There are four different pairs of opening and closing tags which can be used in PHP. Two of those, `<?php ?>` and `<script language="php"> </script>`, are always available. The other two are short tags and ASP  style tags, and can be turned on and off from the php.ini  configuration file. As such, while some people find short tags and ASP style tags convenient, they are less portable, and generally not recommended.
>
> **Short tags** are only available when they are enabled via the short_open_tag  php.ini configuration file directive, or if PHP was configured with the --enable-short-tags option.
>
> **ASP style tags**  are only available when they are enabled via the asp_tags php.ini configuration file directive.

Comment: Can I conclude that the standard tag and the script tags cannot be disabled in anyway ?

Comment: @Zacky yup, the docs are very definite on that (I added another paragraph from the page).

Comment: `<script language="php">` is processed exactly the same as `<?php`, Just because it looks like html does not mean that it is :) - I would also advise you for turning on shortags, there very useful for your view pages.

Answer (score 5):

You should always use the PHP tags `<?php` and `?>`.

These tags will always be available on a PHP server, whereas the shorthand tags (`<?` + `?>`) can be turned on and off in the php.ini file, I generally go with `<?php` `?>` as this increases portability.

Answer (score 1):

so far I know PHP's short opening tag is going to be completed deprecated from PHP 6. So it is beast to use .

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `<?php` tag. You can use `<?` tag when the "short open tag" property is "On" in your php.ini file.