# In which case can we use <% tag on PHP script ? and inside a $variable?

Tags: php, optimization, tags

I just read the php documentation and i read users comments.

Instead of `<?php`,
can we have any problems by using :

```
<%
//your php code here
?>
```

Also i don't really understand a php script on a variable if we turn it into a comment.

```
<?php
  $file_contents  = '<' . '?php die(); ?' . '>' . "\n";
?>
```

Do we have another way to "optimize" it or write it into different way ?
or it is useless ?

Thank you

Comment: The short tags aren't portable. The proper php tags always work, no matter the server's configuration.

Comment: (1) Yes, [but](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3254189/which-php-tags-are-always-available) deprecated. See [php.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) `asp_tags`. (2) Please reexplain what you were trying to do.

Comment: Thank you
<?php is better than <script language="php"> ? 
@mario : just want to know if its possible to use <% without any future problem or just use <?php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are PHP short tags acceptable to use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use)

Answer (score 1):

`<% %>` - This type of tags, called ASP-style, are normally used in ASP language.
You can use them in php if you set `asp_tags = ON` on your php.ini:

ex:

```
; Allow ASP-style <% %> tags.
; http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.asp-tags
asp_tags = ON
```

Not sure why you would ever use ASP-style tags in php, but they exist...
As mentioned by @regality ASP-style tags are **Deprecated**, this means that they'll no longer be available in future versions of php .

You should always use `<?`  or `<?php` to start a block of php code
and `?>` to close it.

ex:

```
<? echo "I'm learning php"; ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo "I'm learning php"; ?>
```

---

In regards to your second question, I cannot find much use - if any - for this code:

```
$file_contents  = '<' . '?php die(); ?' . '>' . "\n";
```

if you want to get the contents of a file you can use:

```
$file_contents = file_get_contents('/tmp/examplefile.txt') ;
echo $file_contents;
```

Comment: Good answer, but you may want to include that ASP style tags are deprecated and should no longer be used.

Comment: Thank you, anyway is i want to comment the entire $variable
<?php
//  $file_contents  = '<?php die(); ?>' . "\n";
?>
I'll get a syntax problem when i'll read ?> do we have better way to write it ?

Comment: What do you want o achieve with `<?php // $file_contents = '<?php die(); ?>' . "\n"; ?>` ?